# Smack API 4.1.2 getting Chat Manager

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I'm trying to make an im client using OpenFire with help of smack's own [documentation.](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/). I established a connection but there is not a getChatManager() method. Here is my code;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
            configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("admin", "cagdas1993");
            configBuilder.setServiceName("service1");
            configBuilder.setHost("localhost");
            configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            configBuilder.setPort(5222);


            AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
            connection.connect();
            connection.login();

            ChatManager chat=connection.getChatManager();//Can't find the method here!

        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I know it must be very easy but couldn't find anything. And if you could give some other example for further it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

starting with Smack 4.1

Comment: I feel like i am the only person having difficulties with this library now i can't get send-get messages, can't add contacts. I've tried many examples and none of them works. Is there a updated document can you suggest

Comment: Besides Smack documentation? No, sorry. Besides, Smack is open source, you should be able to debug most problems yourself.